# java android Multiple addViews on a layout with one xml drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I'm trying get multiple copies of a drawable shape on the layout, but change the color each time. I can't tell if the 2nd imageview is just landing on top of the first. I haven't been able to get them placed in distinct locations to troubleshoot further. Does each instance needs it's own params?

@drawable/circle (circle.xml)

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="#FF888888"/>

<size
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/root">

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.thowell09156277.newcircleaddview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Let's create the missing ImageView
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView image2 = new ImageView(this);
    // Now the layout parameters, these are a little tricky at first
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
    image.setImageTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
    image.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW));
    int imageId;
    imageId = image.generateViewId();
    image.setId(imageId);
    int imageId2;
    imageId2 = image2.generateViewId();
    image2.setId(imageId2);
    image2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
    image2.setImageTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
    image2.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.MAGENTA));
    image2.setId(imageId2);
    //image.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    //params.setMargins(0, 0, 80, 80);
    layout.addView(image, 0, params);
    //params.setMargins(80, 0, 80, 160);
    //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layout.addView(image2, 1, params);
}
```

Comment: You can create a LinearLayout instead rather than RelativeLayout to arrange your views.

Comment: Sorry, I get the same result (one view visible) when I switch everything to LinearLayout. (LinearLayout doesn't support the addRule method, so I just commented those lines out.)